# Python: Reading file line by line and comparing with target

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to read a file line by line from Python and comparing it with target.

Can't seem to print the both variables out:

```
target = 4234789247293487
counter = 0
with open("/Users/admin/Desktop/test3.txt", "r") as p:
for line in p:
    counter = counter + 1
    if line == target:
        print(line)
        print(counter)
```

Comment: Could you post few lines from the file test3.txt?

Comment: Yeah sure. `4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673406432783427834
4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673416432783427834
4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673426432783427834
4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673436432783427834
4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673446432783427834
`

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have posted a code below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should either do `target = str(4234789247293487)` or `if int(line) == target:`, because you are trying to compare an integer with a string.

Comment: If you go with the first way `str()`, you'll need to do `line.strip() == target` because each line in the file will also have a newline character in the end. I wouldn't even mention it, `int(line)` is clearly what @xerox wants.

Answer (score 0):

In the text file it appears those are long strings with a trailing space at the end. In the example below, the first line is changed to have the number from the `target` in the beginning. When the text file is read using `pd.read_csv()` it creates one row with multiple columns. These can then be looped over to print them out. The code below worked with given example.

**Lines from the Text file**

```
4234789247293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673406432783427834 4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673416432783427834 4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673426432783427834 4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673436432783427834 4234789207293487497892349872490564275671497636478264860567240458632746270862834678673446432783427834
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Initialize variables
target = 4234789247293487
counter = 0

# Read the text file
# This creates one row and multiple columns
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/erv/Desktop/test3.txt',sep=" ", header=None)

# Loop over each column
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    line = df.iloc[0][i]
    counter = counter + 1
    #print("\n",line)
    if (str(target) in str(line)):
        print("line: {}".format(line))
        print("counter: {}".format(counter))
        print("\n")
```

**Output**

[image]